# Two Web Views, Two Tabs, Clicking a link in tab1/webview, opens the link in tab2/webview

Tags: ios, webview, tabcontrol

The title says it all.  And I've spent three days now trying to figure it out.  I've used protocols and delegates.  I simply am trying to pass data between tabs, while opening up the link in tab two.  And I am very close to figuring it out, but my problem is right now, is that when I use:

```
        self.tabBarController.selectedViewController
    = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
```

It switches to tab 2, but it doesn't open the link. I have physically click on tab 2, then physically click on tab 1, and then click the link.

I am ready to throw out the hours of time I've put into this, if someone can give me the easiest way to get my question fixed.

Comment: Start by explaining the problem a little better. Your title doesn't say what is wrong. How is Tab 2's webview supposed to open the link? Is there a property that holds the URL and then the viewDidAppear: method triggers the loading of the link?

Comment: I was intentionally trying to be vague with my issue in hopes having a simple solution.    I am starting to think that [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]. - May be the best way to go?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand your question because of some of the terminology, but if I understand you correctly. The way I would solve passing a link from one UIWebview to another would be to utilize the [delegate methods for UIWebview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). Specifically, i'd get the url from the following call on the first UIWebview.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

(You can harvest the url from the NSURLRequest, or just pass along entire request)

and i'd pass it along to the newly loaded tabbarController and the new UIWebview. Using  Something like the following:

```
[secondWebview loadRequest:requestSavedFromFirstWebView];
```

. It's unclear where exactly you are getting hung up.

As far as passing data from one tab in a UITabbar to another. We'd need more information on your setup (as was pointed out in comments). If you can set a public property for the request on your 2nd view controller then you can load it when the viewDidAppear method gets called.

Comment: I that works if it's in the same tab, but I am going to a different tab.  The tab controller is what it's getting hung up on.

Comment: What part of transferring data from one tab to another are you getting hung up on? Are you successfully getting the 2nd viewcontroller access to the request?